# htaccess keeping url without redirecting

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have a few urls which contain book-category in the url. For example, https://www.example.com/abc/book-category/book-1/

I want to load the page in the browser without book-category in the url but still want to load the page content, e.g. if I go to https://www.example.com/abc/book-1/  I want to see the content of https://www.example.com/abc/book-category/book-1/ but still keeping https://www.example.com/abc/book-1/  in the url without redirecting. Is this something I can achieve with some htaccess rules

Answer (score 0):

I understand that "book-category" is a literal, static string ...

That means this rule should work for you:

```
RewriteEnginge on
RewriteRule ^/?abc/book-1/?$ /abc/book-category/book-1/ [L]
```

Often one wants something more generic, though, assuming that "abc" is something fixed you can anchor your rule on:

```
RewriteEnginge on
RewriteRule ^/?abc/([^/]+)/?$ /abc/book-category/$1/ [L]
```

Or maybe both parts of the URL have dynamic character?

```
RewriteEnginge on
RewriteRule ^/?([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /$1/book-category/$2/ [L]
```

In the end on what *exactly* you want to achieve. Your question is vague in that, so I can only make suggestions. Sorry for that.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, I tried that but I am getting page not found, so basically https://www.example.com/abc/book-category/book-1/ loads fine but I don't want to see book-category in the url, after adding the rule to the .htaccess file when I go to https://www.example.com/abc/book-1/ I get 404, but I want to see the same content on the page as the original url, hope this is clear now. Thanks

Comment: That is more or less what that rule does, except of that you contradict yourself now: first the path is `/abc/book-category/book-1/`, now it is `/abc/book-category/book-1` which is something different. Either that is the issue now or something completely different which you did not yet mention in your question. I cannot say.

Comment: Is that configuration file you implemented above rule in considered at all by the http server? How did you make sure?

Comment: Sorry, urls do have / at the end, sorry but how can I ensure above rule is considered by the http server?

Comment: so what I want to achieve is that both urls with or without book-category in them should display the same content

Comment: DId you enable the interpretation of such files at all? You can check by making a simple test: put a definite syntax error in that configuration file. Monitor your http server's error log file and make a test request. What do you see?

Comment: I got it working with reverse proxy but couldn't get it working with htaccess file. Thanks for your help anyways.